# How to run javascript function when reaching an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to run a javascript `function` when you pass a page section? What I am trying to achieve is something akin to Twitter Bootstrap's scrollspy.

Comment: Would you like to trigger a function when the users mouse cursor reaches a section or when the page the scrolled and that content is in the visible window area?

Comment: When the page scrolled and that content is in the visible window area.

Comment: Post that as an answer, @roasted so I can accept it :D Perfect!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `waypoints` plugin:

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

> Waypoints is a jQuery plugin that makes it easy to execute a function
>   whenever you scroll to an element.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tGggU/1/)  that accomplishes the behavior you are looking for by registering a custom event on the `a` elements that's triggered based on a logic that you can customize as you see fit.

In the example the event is triggered when the `a` elements' position is within the range 0 to 100 from the top of the visible portion of the document.

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('a').on('reached', function() {
        alert('Reached ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        $('a').each(function() {
            var wt = $(window).scrollTop();
            var at = $(this).position().top;
            var dt = at - wt;
            if( dt >= 0 && dt < 100)
                $(this).trigger('reached');
        });
    });
})
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use scrollTop function of jQuery.

You can get the anchor tag position using position() function and tries to match it with scrollTop return value.